# Не переведена всплывающая подсказка у меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Некоторое время назад у меток появились новые всплывающие подсказки с кнопками «Подписаться» и «Игнорировать». Однако у этих кнопок и области с количеством подписчиков на метку отсутствует перевод. Также перевод сбился у ссылки на страницу информации по метке.

[image: Экранный снимок всплывающей подсказки]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переводы для новых функций уже добавлены и будут обновлены на сайте в ближайшее время.

Спасибо за вашу внимательность!

Comment: Похоже всплывающая подсказка не адаптирована для таких длинных слов. Надо сделать переведенную версию короче, либо что-то делать со стилями! https://i.stack.imgur.com/33l4m.png

Comment: @АндрейNOP сейчас будет хотфикс, спасибо )

Comment: Кстати, как насчёт более простого «Следить»?

Comment: @andreymal тогда нужно везде вставлять предлог «за». Ну, и термин устоявшийся, кажется: отслеживание посылок, все такое.

Comment: Там еще, кстати, всплывающая подсказка не переведена: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Z71.png

Comment: @АндрейNOP при следующей подгрузке обновится, спасибо.